# Calculating average count on each row in Postgres 11.7 without a CROSS JOIN

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm trying to figure out the best way to attach an overall average of a count to each row in Postgres 11.7. I'm frequently interested in the average of a count, but have found it unexpectedly awkward to calculate in SQL. I suspect I'm missing something pretty basic. I've set up a toy table to work with:

```
BEGIN:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS progress CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS progress (
    package_id     integer     NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    completed_dts  timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    step           citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO progress (package_id, completed_dts, step) VALUES
    (1,'2020-01-01 01:00:00.000000+10','Assemble'),
    (1,'2020-01-01 01:15:00.000000+10','Inspect'),
    (1,'2020-01-01 01:25:00.000000+10','Box'),

    (2,'2020-01-01 01:00:00.000000+10','Pull'),
    (2,'2020-01-01 01:10:00.000000+10','Inspect'),
    (2,'2020-01-01 01:13:00.000000+10','Dispatch'),

    (3,'2020-01-01 01:00:00.000000+10','Assemble');

COMMIT;
```

There are three packages in progress, `1`, `2`, and `3`. Both `1` and `2` have three steps, while `3` has one step. So, the average is `7/3 = 2.333...`. This is the target output:

```
package_id    step_count    step_avg
1             3             2.3333333333333333
2             3             2.3333333333333333
3             1             2.3333333333333333
```

I've hunted down a lot of threads here, and examples elsewhere. It looks like the overall average can be calculated using a subquery or CTE. Here's the CTE version:

```
WITH steps AS (
  select package_id,
         count(*) AS step_count      

    from progress

 group by package_id)

select avg(step_count) from steps;
```

Here's the subquery alternative:

```
select avg(total_steps) 
  from 
     (  select count(*) AS total_steps 
        from progress 
    group by package_id) AS steps_count
```

It *feels* like what I want is a window function, something like this:

```
   select package_id,
          count(*) as step_count,
          avg(count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY package_id)) as step_count_avg

     from progress 

 group by package_id
 order by package_id
```

This does not work:

```
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
LINE 3:           avg(count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY package_id)) as st...
                      ^. (Line 9)
```

I've not found any way to combine the average with my grouping query short of a `CROSS JOIN`. This produces the correct output:

```
-- Group the records and get the count(*).
WITH 
steps AS (
  select package_id,
         count(*) AS step_count      

    from progress

 group by package_id),

-- Calculate the step average.
 step_summary AS (
   select avg(step_count) AS step_avg from steps
   )

-- CROSS JOIN to agglutinate the results
  select steps.package_id,
         steps.step_count,
         step_summary.step_avg

    from steps,
         step_summary

order by package_id
```

This seems a bit over the top. Is there a more straightforward and efficient way to get an overall value like this?

For background:
* Our real tables will have 10s of millions of rows. (Only 2.5M now for a test data set.)

- I'm only looking at `avg(count())` here, but we've got other examples of `aggregate(aggregate())` to implement as well.
- Simply attaching the average to a combined output without the `CROSS JOIN` also seemed to fail completely.
- We're generating output like this for import into Domo, which likes redundant values on each row.
- Yes, we can use temp tables, or rollup tables, if necessary. But I'm also keen to figure out the simplest way to integrate `aggregate(aggregate())` results in queries generally.

## Suggestion Follow-up

Here's a link to an old Oracle thread with a really close question:

[SQL AVG(COUNT(*))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800347/sql-avgcount)

If I've understood that thread correctly, here's a rewrite of my query with two CTEs and no `CROSS JOIN`:

```
with 
step_total as 
(
    select package_id, count(*) as step_count
    from progress
    group by package_id
),

step_stats as
(
    select package_id, 
           step_count, 
           avg(step_count) over (partition by package_id) as average

    from step_total
)

select *
from step_stats
```

This provides an average *per row*, which is going to equal the `count(*)`, in this case. What I'm trying to get is the *overall* average of `2.3333....` bolted onto each row. Here's what the query above returns for me:

```
package_id  step_count  average
1           3           3
2           3           3
3           1           1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL AVG(COUNT(\*))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800347/sql-avgcount)

Comment: That's a solid link I would _not_ have found. But II don't think it achieves what I'm after. I'm not trying to calculate a total on each row, Im trying to add the overall average to each row. I've posted the code that I tried in my question, in case I've rewritten the example incorrectly

Comment: I merely googled 'average of a count sql site:stackoverflow.com before:2011'. Google re advanced googling. SO search is bad. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. But first one must pin down each specific place one doesn't get what one expects.

Comment: The point is, aggregate to get subqueries then join on appropriate superkeys. There is a class of common errors where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregations over appropriate rows and/or aggregate a case statement picking rows; join on a unique column set. Sometimes DISTINCT aggregation picks the right values after a non-key join.

Comment: For sure, I'm making common mistakes here. I've set up the toy example so that it's simple enough to figure out the expected results in my head. I'm also trying to work out window functions for various results. Unfortunately, I don't follow your comment well enough to apply it. I expect you're busy, but could you possibly write a short sample of what your'e talking about with my toy table? If you don't have time, thanks anyway.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can dthat is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: ? The top of my question specifies the environment, has the script needed to set up the sample table, including data, and is followed by an example of the target output. It also includes a sample of working code with a `CROSS JOIN`, along with some notes on failed attempts to show some additional effort. I'm unclear what about that isn't a good question.